# Python elasticsearch-dsl django pagination

Tags: python, django, pagination, elasticsearch-dsl

How can i use django pagination on elasticsearch dsl.
My code:

```
query = MultiMatch(query=q, fields=['title', 'body'], fuzziness='AUTO')

s = Search(using=elastic_client, index='post').query(query).sort('-created_at')
response = s.execute()

// this always returns page count 1
paginator = Paginator(response, 100)
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    posts = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    posts = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found this paginator on this [link](https://github.com/jaddison/django-simple-elasticsearch/blob/0.9.11/simple_elasticsearch/forms.py):

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, Page

class DSEPaginator(Paginator):
    """
    Override Django's built-in Paginator class to take in a count/total number of items;
    Elasticsearch provides the total as a part of the query results, so we can minimize hits.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DSEPaginator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._count = self.object_list.hits.total

    def page(self, number):
        # this is overridden to prevent any slicing of the object_list - Elasticsearch has
        # returned the sliced data already.
        number = self.validate_number(number)
        return Page(self.object_list, number, self)
```

and then in view i use:

```
    q = request.GET.get('q', None)
    page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    start = (page-1) * 10
    end = start + 10

    query = MultiMatch(query=q, fields=['title', 'body'], fuzziness='AUTO')
    s = Search(using=elastic_client, index='post').query(query)[start:end]
    response = s.execute()

    paginator = DSEPaginator(response, settings.POSTS_PER_PAGE)
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

this way it works perfectly..

Comment: the `count` property in this example just shows the number of items in the page not the total. you can override the `count` cached_property of the paginator to return `_count` as the total count

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice from Danielle Madeley, I also created a proxy to search results which works well with the latest version of `django-elasticsearch-dsl==0.4.4`.

```
from django.utils.functional import LazyObject

class SearchResults(LazyObject):
    def __init__(self, search_object):
        self._wrapped = search_object

    def __len__(self):
        return self._wrapped.count()

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        search_results = self._wrapped[index]
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            search_results = list(search_results)
        return search_results
```

Then you can use it in your search view like this:

```
paginate_by = 20
search = MyModelDocument.search()
# ... do some filtering ...
search_results = SearchResults(search)

paginator = Paginator(search_results, paginate_by)
page_number = request.GET.get("page")
try:
    page = paginator.page(page_number)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page parameter is not an integer, show first page.
    page = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page parameter is out of range, show last existing page.
    page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

Django's LazyObject proxies all attributes and methods from the object assigned to the _wrapped attribute. I am overriding a couple of methods that are required by Django's paginator, but don't work out of the box with the Search() instances.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution is to use [MultipleObjectMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/) and extract your Elastic results in `get_queryset()` by overriding it. In this case Django will take care of the pagination itself if you add the `paginate_by` attribute.

It should look like that:

```
class MyView(MultipleObjectMixin, ListView):
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        object_list = []
        """ Query Elastic here and return the response data in `object_list`.
            If you wish to add filters when querying Elastic,
            you can use self.request.GET params here. """
        return object_list
```

**Note:** The code above is broad and different from my own case so I can not guarantee it works. I used similar solution by inheriting other Mixins, overriding `get_queryset()` and taking advantage of Django's built in pagination - it worked great for me. As it was an easy fix I decided to post it here with a similar example.

Comment: It also works great with DRF without any additional code. Just return `Search` object in the `get_queryset`, that's all

Answer (score 0):

Another way forward is to create a proxy between the `Paginator` and the Elasticsearch query. `Paginator` requires two things, `__len__` (or `count`) and `__getitem__` (that takes a slice). A rough version of the proxy works like this:

```
class ResultsProxy(object):
    """
    A proxy object for returning Elasticsearch results that is able to be
    passed to a Paginator.
    """

    def __init__(self, es, index=None, body=None):
        self.es = es
        self.index = index
        self.body = body

    def __len__(self):
        result = self.es.count(index=self.index,
                               body=self.body)
        return result['count']

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        assert isinstance(item, slice)

        results = self.es.search(
            index=self.index,
            body=self.body,
            from_=item.start,
            size=item.stop - item.start,
        )

        return results['hits']['hits']
```

A proxy instance can be passed to `Paginator` and will make requests to ES as needed.

Answer (score 0):

For django 4+ with drf, it is by-the-book solution but I will put it in here, because it took me like 2 hours to find out.

```
class DSLPaginator(Paginator):
    """
    Override Django's built-in Paginator class to take in a count/total number of items;
    Elasticsearch provides the total as a part of the query results, so we can minimize hits.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.count = self.object_list.hits.total["value"]

    def page(self, number):
        # this is overridden to prevent any slicing of the object_list - Elasticsearch has
        # returned the sliced data already.
        number = self.validate_number(number)
        return Page(self.object_list, number, self)


class ESPageNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    django_paginator_class = DSLPaginator
    page_size = 12
```

With DRF, use it like this:

```
class VideoListESView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = VideoListESSerializer
    model = serializer_class.Meta.model
    pagination_class = ESPageNumberPagination

    def get_queryset(self):    
        page = int(self.request.GET.get("page", 1))
        page_size = self.pagination_class.page_size
        s = VideoDocument.search()[(page - 1) * page_size : page * page_size].sort({"id": {"order": "desc"}}).execute()
        return s
```