# How to make my django-el-pagination page loads faster?

Tags: python, django

I am using django-el-pagination in Django project to show documents.

But I found that when I have **more than 90k documents**,
the page **loads very slowly**.

I think that **'get_queryset' function runs again**  when sending ajax to load more.

This makes page load slowly.

Is there any way to slice the existing objects list instead of query all objects again.

```
class IndexView(AjaxListView):
    template_name = 'entry/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'entity_list'
    page_template = 'entry/entry_list_page.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        <--My code to get objects-->
        return <objects>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear and information is also very short, please revise question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, my old code query all objects every time,

`return Entry.objects.filter().order_by('date')[::-1]`

and the new code will run internal query command to query severl objects each time.

`return Entry.objects.filter().order_by('date')`

With elasticsearch, I use the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48104761/6700079), it create a proxy between the Paginator and the Elasticsearch query.